# AWS Glue: How to decide how many worker nodes are required for my job to complete

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have 70 folders and each folder contains approximately 700 files. I have a glue job which merges the files from each folder and stores the single file (used repartition(1) for getting single merged file) in another location containing 70 folders.

**Example**: source_location named as loc1 has 700 files
Output: dest_location having same folder name loc1 will have 1 merged file.

I am also using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_worker=4)`,
configured glue with spark type, glue version 4, worker type G2X, max no. of workers 4 and max concurrency 3.

Still I am get `OutOfMemoryException: Failure allocating buffer.`

Metric show active executor is only 1.5 Any insights on this issue? [Picture of executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Fz1.jpg).

The main aim is to merge all files from respective folders and put it in folder wise structure in a different location. Out of 70 folders 50 folders are successfully merged but while processing the rest I am getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not number of workers. `OutOfMemoryException: Failure allocating buffer` means it doesn't have RAM. I don't know your code and you have not told us the size of data but I would guess you are loading all the files into RAM. If all your files have total size of 1TB and you load all of it to RAM, you require a little more than 1TB RAM.

If by merging two files you mean append the content of one file into another, consider using an append method like `open(file, "a")` [in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032903/whether-my-file-is-opened-in-ram-while-in-append-mode) or `>>` in bash - this way you do not load the file you are appending to, in RAM. This does not work for all file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the size of files you are merging. You mentioned that you are using G2.X node type which you will get 32GB of memory per node. While merging the data will be accumulated to single node. If the combined size of all 700 files from single folder is more than 32GB then you will definitely get out of memory exception. Try increasing the node type that will match the size of all your files combinedly.